# Keras: Is it possible to use model.evaluate() for checkpoints rather than model.fit metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

It's well known that when fitting a keras model, the metrics that are reported include all the layers including dropouts. As such, reported metrics (precision, recall, f1, even accuracy) will differ from what was reported during the fit, and when using the predicted results using model.predict().

I'm curious whether it is possible to have keras perform checkpoints on a user-defined routine that uses the current model.predict() rather than the internal metric.

Example:

```
model.fit(X,y,validation_data=(Xv,yv),\
  callbacks=[K.ModelCheckpoint('/tmp/dump.h5',\ 
  monitor='val_acc')])
```

will perform checkpoints on the validation accuracy that's been measured during the fit (and reported using `verbose=1`). But suppose I want to perform the checkpoint with F1-score using the actual predictions that model would make on the validation set. Is it possible to get `ModelCheckpoint` to use something like `sklearn.metrics.f1_score(yv,model.predict(Xv))`?

Comment: Do you want to have a custom metric calculated every time the validation is executed?

Comment: Yes. I want to report the f1_score on the model using mode.predict() so that the dropouts are turned off.

Comment: And adding the metric, while compiling the model, does not fit your needs? You can just pass the callbacks there

Comment: That's not what I need. I can get it to use the metric during callback, but it uses the training model which includes dropout. I need the metric to NOT include the dropout.  At the moment I'm doing this manually after the training is completed, but it would be nice to see this value as training goes on (after each epoch).

Comment: Keras does not use dropout, while the validation